# Do we have ChatGPT policy?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, policy

I recently noticed an answer which, according to the author, was written by ChatGPT. The question was very poor (about quantum entanglement, from a person who have learned about entanglement from a popular magazine). I thought it can't be reasonably answered, but ChatGPT understood what kind of answer is expected (popular, without long deep explanations). That makes me think, are ChatGPT answers (or answers from another AI service) allowed?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14281/2451