# Do we have to be nice to chatbots?

Tags: discussion, policy

I referred to Google Bard in a comment as a “confident idiot” and the comment was deleted. Did I violate the “Be nice” policy, or was the comment deleted for another reason?

Comment: That is what euphemisms are for.

Comment: About these shorthand forms, like LLM.  They may make sense to *you* but not everyone will know what you mean and they can have multiple other meanings.  Just spell out the whole thing - it's simpler for everyone.

Comment: Echoing @StephenG - Help Ukraine consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 10):

I primarily deleted this as it was an answer to a closed question. Comments should be used to suggest changes to a post, not to answer them.

The rudeness did affect my decision somewhat. I was not actually aware that Google Bard was a chatbot, and assumed it was the username or pseudonym of some real person that developed this theory. This doesn't really change that the comment serves no useful purpose.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't delete your comment, and I haven't discussed it with the moderator who did.

If you believe that a chatbot has passed Stack Exchange's captchas and is posting on its own, that is a much more interesting problem than whether we should be polite to them. But if a person is copying and pasting some chatbot's output, we owe it to ourselves to be kind to that person.

That said, [chatbot-generated "theories" are a waste of everyone's time](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14281/44126). Don't give them oxygen by coming up with clever zingers about them. Flag as rude/abusive and move on.

Comment: *If you believe that a chatbot has passed Stack Exchange's captchas and is posting on its own…* No, I don’t believe that.

Comment: Well, should they get to that point, being polite to it might well be in order…