# Scratch/sandbox area where I can try formatting my equations

Tags: support, mathjax

Is there a sandbox area where I could test the formatting of my equations without the 5 minute reply limit kicking in?

I have a long set of equations to type and I'm trying to learn how to format stuff on StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [this sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) on meta.math.se that seems to be set up for the purpose you propose.

Answer (score 3):

When you type in the answer box, a preview of your answer appears below the box where you're typing. That preview includes the rendered MathJax. Just look at the preview to see how your post is going to look.

If you're talking about checking comments before you post them, you can still use the answer box as a previewer. Compose your comment in the answer box and copy and paste the Markdown into the comment box. The MathJax rendering is the same between comments and answers. Just try to avoid display-style equations (with `$$...$$` or `\begin{align}...\end{align}` etc.) in comments.

Comment: Thank you @David Z!

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an off-site markdown editor where you can write drafts of Stack Exchange posts and see their formatting (including math), and save these drafts to come back to later, then [**StackEdit**](https://stackedit.io/) is probably the best tool for the job.

[image: StackEdit screenshot]

<sup>(No affiliation or relation, by the way.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It seems natural to mention that meta actually has a [sandbox](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/389/2451) (although MathJax/TeX does not work here).