# Is this legal to post my physics question here for verification only but not for answer?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, homework-and-exercises

Is this legal to post my physics question here for **verification** only but **not** for answer?

I just want to make sure that my question is on-topic, not off-topic, and fits the rules, like it's **not** too broad and etc.

I have already read all the "How to ask" sections on the help center and then in physics stack exchange.com I have asked 2 questions, attempted that these 2 questions will be good, but they were**n't** well received and I have reached my question limit so quickly.

So from now on I want to post my physics question here for validation purposes only and if it passes then I will post it on physics stack exchange.com for answers.

Is this legal?

This is analogous to the idea when you have created an application and you want first to test it in QA and release beta version of that application first before releasing the released version of the application to the customer, because you never can know if you have bugs in the application you are developing or not.

So I **never** know if my question will get downvoted or not.

If my third physics question will be bad as the two others on physics stack exchange.com then I wo**n't** be able to ask questions there anymore and I do**n't** want to be in this state so I am **not** taking risks anymore.

Comment: No one can tell you whether your question will be downvoted or not. You could ask such questions (about how to ask a particular question on the main site) in the Physics chat room instead of meta.

Comment: In general, Meta should not turn into a go/no go site to judge the quality of questions. The purpose of Meta is to discuss how the site should be run. Write a good question, basing how good it is on other up voted questions on the main site.

Comment: Duplicate: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/  see also https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5959

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're having trouble crafting questions that are well-received on the main site, I don't think posting them here for "pre-approval" would be well-received either.

We do have [a sandbox question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/389/44126), but that's for experimenting with formatting rather than experimenting with content.

If you have a question that you don't think is a good fit for the main site, you might politely try to discuss your question in [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).
We have several active voters and answerers who are regularly available in the chat room, and I believe there have been a few cases of questions that have started off in chat as "I have this vague issue about blah" but were refined into much clearer language in chat discussions before getting posted.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule we like questions to be useful to a wide audience. If you post a question that just asks *Did I get this right?* that question isn't likely to be of interest to anyone but you, and the question will probably end up being downvoted and closed.

However let me second Rob's suggestion to ask [in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). You can ask anything in the chat room, and we do quite often get students asking about course work. Whether you get a reply, and how quickly you get a reply, will depend on who is in the chat room at the time, but it's always worth asking.